# Sub domain pretty URL in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a sub domain for my application (http://articles.myloanguroo.com/inside.php/?short=1). Now I want to create a pretty URL for this like (http://articles.myloanguroo.com/inside/1)

My [.htaccess file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ inside.php?short=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myloanguroo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.myloanguroo\.com$ [NC]
```

This is not working for me and is showing a 404 error.

How can I create subdomain pretty URLs in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should start with `^inside/` and keep conditions before `RewriteRule`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.myloanguroo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^inside/(\w+)/?$ inside.php?short=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply. But still it its not working. If i pass (http://articles.myloanguroo.com/inside/value) , showing Notice: Undefined variable: short in /home/myloang/public_html/articles/inside.php on line 5, and if i pass value like that how to retrieve that values please help me.

Comment: Where is `/articles/` coming from in your URL since it is not part of my rule? Also did you use `Options -MultiViews` as suggested?

Comment: btw your original URL `http://articles.myloanguroo.com/inside.php/?short=1` is also showing some error on `Undefined variable`

Comment: Articles is inside folder. i created sub domain for that folder. If i use Options -MultiViews it showing 404 error.

Comment: You have to use `Options -MultiViews`. Also what is location of `.htaccess` and `inside.php`. You need to clarify about your filesystem structure.

Comment: inside.php and .htaccess are located at /myloanguroo.com/articles/. i mean inside article sub folder

Comment: ok comment out all 4 `RewriteCond` lines above and then retest (keep `Options -MultiViews` line)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61159/discussion-between-anubhava-and-dileep-kumar).